# Create Lookup Connection to another object via text match

Tags: apex

EDIT - I tried a different approach and got some traction...

Trying to match a user-entered Country value to a table of 'permutations' to then correct and update the country name, as well as link to the "Country Mapping" object record for that country.

This is the logic and process:

IF Country = CA  map against country code
                BillingCountry updated to Canada
                Country_Mapping__c = Canada (record on Country Mapping object)

If Country = Can OR Canadia  map against permutations
                CillingCountry updated to Canada
                Country_Mapping__c = Canada

What am I missing, as nothing is happening upon execute for the permutations.

trigger AccountSetCountryMap on Account (before insert, before update) {

```
String UpperCountry;
String Lookup;

Set<String> Country= new Set<String>();
for(Account record : Trigger.new){
    UpperCountry = record.BillingCountry.toUpperCase();
    Lookup = '%'+record.BillingCountry+'%';
    Country.add(UpperCountry);
   }


Map<String,Country_Mapping__c> CountryMap = new Map<String,Country_Mapping__c>();
    for(Country_Mapping__c CM : [Select ID, Country__c, Permutations__c from     Country_Mapping__c where Permutations__c LIKE :Lookup])
    CountryMap.put(CM.Permutations__c, CM);  

for(Account record : Trigger.new) {       
            UpperCountry = record.BillingCountry.toUpperCase();
            if(record.BillingCountry!= null && CountryMap.containsKey(UpperCountry))
                record.BillingCountry = CountryMap.get(UpperCountry).Country__c;
    }        

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error on screen?

Comment: Can you tell where is your problem? Is this query 'Select ID, Country__c, Permutations__c from Country_Mapping__c 
                                         where Permutations__c LIKE '%can%' LIMIT 1' returns a result when run in dev console?

Comment: This query works --> Select ID, Country__c, Permutations__c from Country_Mapping__c where Permutations__c LIKE '%CAN%' LIMIT 1

Comment: you have declared country as a set. so I believe'String Lookup = '%'+Country+'%';' will be giving you an error

Comment: Agreed... passed the variable to another field and got this %{USA}%.  Where are these { and } coming from?

Comment: toString() of Set. You will see the same when you do System.debug(country);

Comment: Your requirement looks little complex to me. As you are trying to get the country based on few alphabets. e.g. user enters only 'I' so which one would you chose India or Indonesia. If I had a similar requirement then I would like to create a picklist to choose country rather then a text field. I wuld like to know how you solve this.

Comment: Still can't get the LIKE SOQL to work.

Answer (score 0):

Acc variable is null

```
Account Acc;

Country_Mapping__c[] CMap = [Select ID, Country__c, Country_Code__c from Country_Mapping__c 
                             where Country_Code__c like :Acc.BillingCountry LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: It is the loop variable... so it can't be null.

Comment: I couldn't get you @AdrianLarson. Can you please tell me how this will get a value? What I saw is a declaration but no initialization in line 3 and used in line 4 just after trigger.

Comment: Ah, only saw it as the loop variable later on. Duplicate variable shouldn't even compile...